# Oracle Goldengate replication and changing tables structure

Tags: postgresql, oracle, replication, ddl, oracle-golden-gate

I have a table in Oracle Database and the same table in PostgreSQL Database.
Structure of the table is different, so I have mapping in replicat to resolve fields mismatch.
I want to make some changes to the structure of the table on Oracle site.
As I know there's no way to automatically replicate DDL changes between Oracle and PostgreSQL databases.
So I have to perform all changes manually.
Is this the right way to perform this?

1. Stop application on both sites to prevent data changes in the table
2. Stop extracts/replicats for the table
3. Delete trandata for the table
4. Add columns in the table on both sites
5. Add the mapping for new column in replicat
6. Add trandata for the table
7. Start extract/replicat
8. Start application

Is everything correct?
Maybe there is something I forgot?

Comment: What happend when you tested this setup?